# Can't extract files to opt folder

Tags: centos, software-installation

I'm having difficulty extracting clion into the opt folder. I'm in the proper folder, there are no typos, nothing seems to work. I've even tried using the GUI extractor and pointed to the `opt` folder and that doesn't work either.

Anyway, here's what I get when I try to extract the file

```
[denis@localhost clion]$ ls
CLion-2018.2.4.tar.gz                                           
[denis@localhost clion]$ sudo tar xf Clion-2018.2.4.tar.gz -C /opt/
tar: Clion-2018.2.4.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I'm using CentOS7.

Answer (score 6):

You have a typo in the file name. The one in the directory has an uppercase `L` as its second character. Your `tar` command tries to reference a file with a lowercase `l` as its second character.

Linux/UNIX filesystems are almost always case sensitive.

Generally, it's good practice to specify the `z` character on your `tar` command to signify that you know you're dealing with a compressed file (`gz`). You don't need it, but it's good to include it.

```
tar xzf CLion-2018.2.4.tar.gz -C /opt
```